# decoding JSON where tags are values

Tags: java, json, jackson

I have a JSON file that's formatted like this:

```
{
  "Cubs": {
    "city": "Chicago",
    "league": "National",
    "division": "Central"
  },
  "Cardinals": {
    "city": "St. Louis",
    "league": "National",
    "division": "Central"
  }
}
```

What I'd like to get out of parsing it is a `Map<String,TeamInfo>` where the key is the team name.

I'm trying to use Jackson to decode this - the structures of the information for the teams is pretty well defined, but the tags are the names of the teams. I don't have control over the input format, this is what we use.

I've tried parsing it this way:

```
public static class TeamInfo {
    private String city;
    private String league;
    private String division;

    public TeamInfo() {
    }

    public String getCity() {
        return city;
    }

    public void setCity(String city) {
        this.city = city;
    }

    public String getLeague() {
        return league;
    }

    public void setLeague(String league) {
        this.league = league;
    }

    public String getDivision() {
        return division;
    }

    public void setDivision(String division) {
        this.division = division;
    }
}

public Map<String, TeamInfo> parseTeamInfo(String inputFile) {
    Map<String, TeamInfo> teamInfo = null;
    try {
        teamInfo = m_objectMapper.readValue(inputFile, Map.class);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return teamInfo;
}
```

It parses just fine, but the resulting object is a Map of Maps rather than a Map of TeamInfo's.

[image: result]

It feels close yet far away at the the same time. Any thoughts on things to try?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Think this should work for you:

```
public Map<String, TeamInfo> parseTeamInfo(String inputFile) {
    Map<String, TeamInfo> teamInfo = null;
    try {
        TypeReference<HashMap<String,TeamInfo>> typeRef 
            = new TypeReference<HashMap<String,TeamInfo>>() {};

        HashMap<String,TeamInfo> o = mapper.readValue(inputFile, typeRef); 
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return teamInfo;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! This got it perfectly.